# how to prevent jsp page reloading

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I am getting data properly from the database and displayed in the JSP page for the first time. When I Refresh the page the page appears blank and continue to show blank data even I refresh again and again. To get proper data, I had to close and open the JSP page in a new window. What is the problem?. I am using tomcat Server.

Comment: Can any one help me???

Comment: i can not understant what you mean, maybe post your code is perfect.

Comment: here i am posting my code: